# HTML5 - Video freezes on heavy page processing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am trying to display a video on a page that does heavy processing, meaning many HTML controls that update and change over time grids, charts, etc) and that their processing is constantly happening. The problem is that when I reach a heavy load of updating HTML elements the video freezes (using Chrome 61). 
Is there any way around it? like rendering specific HTML elements (the video) from another thread (somehow using web-workers?)
I assume that other people may have reached this problem on video or other live-updating controls (rendered canvas etc...) on single page apps, is there a solution?

Example of such code below, obviously the example isn't of a real code but made of samples, but it demonstrates the idea.

Would appreciate some help.
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>||Working with elements||</title>
</head>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" autoplay controls>
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addElement () { 
for (i=0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
  // create a new div element 
  // and give it some content 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
  }
}
</script>
<div id="div1">The text above has been created dynamically.</div>
<input type=button onclick="addElement()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML and JavaScript that you have tried at Question? What do you mean by "Video freezes"?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: How is the code at Question related to `<canvas>` and `<video>` elements? What is the purpose of appending `1000000` elements to `document`?

Comment: As I said the example code is not a real code, it simply shows the problem, both canvas rendering / video elements are live updating elements in a page, if their rendering would freeze the user would experience it and feel it. I am trying to understand how to prevent it. The adding of 1000000 lines simply shows what happens when an HTML page updates frequently.

Comment: What do you mean by "canvas rendering" and "live updating"? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: By canvas rendering I mean displaying a canvas that shows movement or implementing video alone by changing images. The entire concept I mean that is problematic("live update") here are things that are changing very fast that their temporary pause would cause the UX to be bad. For example if a user looks at a grid of updating numbers, if it will take another 200ms for a cell to update he won't notice, cause the number will only update a bit later, but if a video pauses, the user will notice immediately.

Comment: Have you read the links at previous comment? Can you include the actual code that you are referencing at Question?

Comment: I have. I can't give the specific code because it's not written yet, I am talking here about a concept problem, the solution i'm looking for isn't to "make sure your other code is efficient enough so it won't happen", if I'll create a page that enough elements are updating frequently it will overload the main thread at some points and I don't want my video to be affected by it. Thanks.

Comment: _"I can't give the specific code because it's not written yet"_ The Question does not have a clear problem statement.

Comment: I've written a sample code of the problem I am trying to fix, for reference, I had the same problem with C# WinForms in the past and had to create a work around to fix it. The code above reflects the problem, please refer to it.

Comment: "Video freezes on heavy page processing" cannot be reproduced by code at Question. There is no problem relating to `<canvas>` or `<video>` element at code at Question. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.